# Excel Analysis between 2 columns

Tags: compare, analysis

Looking to do analysis in excel on two columns. I’m trying to compare the current [N] to the Proposed [Y]. How would I go about doing this?

CURRENT  NYYYN vs

PROPOSED YYYYN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you only have "Y" and "N" value in current column,
just write =IF(A2="Y","N","Y") in the Proposed column 2nd cell and extract it to all column

Comment: Great that IF function worked. How can I express the analysis mathematically?